# What would happen if the filibuster rule was abolished in the current US Senate?

Tags: united-states, senate, senate-rules, filibuster

Active senators from each party at present:

> Republican  - 50
> Democratic  - 48
> Independent -  2

The Independent Senators often align with the Democrats, so many bills end up in 50-50 tie.  Without the filibuster rule:

1. Does the voting right of the VP still exist?
2. If the VP had no voting right, would a bill be considered "passed" simply with 50 votes from either side?

Comment: The filibuster has no impact on something passing or not passing it just prevents it from coming up for a vote unless there are 60 votes to stop debate on it. The item still requires a separate vote with the required number of votes to pass.

Comment: question 2 is impossible to answer. How can we know what the framers would have written if they hadn't given the VP the tie-breaking vote?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tie-breaking vote that the VP has in the US Senate is set in the Constitution.  The filibuster is set out in the rules of the Senate.

If the Senate decides to remove the ability to filibuster, it has no impact on the VP having a tie-breaking vote.

Comment: You are correct. I didn't do enough HW before asking. Thanks.